# Integration of orientdb with spark

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I want to integrate an orienddb database with spark.so so I can fetch records anb run queries through spark.

Can someone advice me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OrientDB-Spark plugin: https://github.com/orientechnologies/spark-orientdb.